# Why do many DJs use a large number of pseudonyms?

Tags: names, dj

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darren_Tate?wprov=sfla1:

> Like many of his fellow DJs, Tate has used a large number of pseudonyms.

Why do many DJs use a large number of pseudonyms? Is that in case they mix or produce several types of music, and prefer to use 1 name per type?

Comment: I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: Any ideas are welcome.